# Getting :type-at information for a long list of modules in ghci

Tags: haskell, ghc, ghci

I am interested in getting the output of the :type-at command in GHCI for a long list of modules.  It works fine if I manually do `:type-at MyFile.hs M N M P`; however, for this many modules I'd rather have a way to automate the process of finding out that information and storing it to a file.

Is there
a) a way to use ghci with an input file which tells it all the commands to process, or
b) a way to define a macro that lets me loop through a list of values and apply the :type-at command to all of those values?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a) a way to use ghci with an input file which tells it all the commands to process

There is. You can define a custom `:source` command as follows:

```
> :def source readFile
> let x = length "hello"
> :source GHCiTest.txt
x :: Int
5
5
x :: Int        -- Defined at <interactive>:6:5
hello
```

In the above example, the `GHCiTest.txt` contained the following GHCi commands, which were run one by one by `:source`:

```
:t x
print x
x
:i x
putStrLn "hello"
```

Alternatively, you could start GHCi using a custom `.ghci` file which is automatically `:source`d at startup.